# Mongoose : don't insert if element already stored

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB and Mongoose with Express to store tweets that I retrieve via the Twitter API.

I want to avoid saving duplicate tweets. I am doing something like that :

```js
TweetsModel.find({tweet_id: tweet.tweet_id}, function (err, tweets) {
    if(tweets.length > 0){
        cb('Tweet already exists',null);
    } else{
        tweet.save(function(err){
            cb(err,user);
        });
    }
});
```

My question is : for performance reason, is there a way using Mongoose to avoid doing two requests ? One find and one save ?

Knowing that I don't want to update the tweet if it already exists either.

Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use an `update` call with the [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-parameter) option to do this:

```js
TweetsModel.update(
    {tweet_id: tweet.tweet_id}, 
    {$setOnInsert: tweet}, 
    {upsert: true}, 
    function(err, numAffected) { .. }
);
```

If a doc already exists with that tweet id, then this is a no-op.  Otherwise it will add the doc.

`$setOnInsert` requires v2.4+ of MongoDB.  If your version is less than 2.4, things get more complicated.

Comment: I think that has to be `$setOnInsert : tweet`, otherwise the rest of the document won't get saved.

Comment: For MongoDB < 2.4 I would perhaps use a uniqueness constraint (and check for [11000-errors](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/error-codes/)), since `$set` would update an existing document in the database (which @tomahim doesn't want).

Comment: @robertklep Yeah, it gets a lot messier in that case.  Hopefully he's at 2.4.