# How to update the document if it exist else save it?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update the document if it exist else save it. I am using below code from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20312163/mongoose-dont-insert-if-element-already-stored)

```
user.update({User_id:req.body.User_id}, {$setOnInsert: req.body},
            {upsert: true}, function (err, data) {
  if(err) { 
    res.json(err);
  } else {
    res.json('Successfully  inserted ');
  }
});
```

but it is throwing the below error

```
TypeError: oldCb is not a function
```

Comment: Read the docs about upserts.

Comment: use $set instead of $setOnInsert

Comment: @Subham  not working same error

Comment: try to manually set data like {
                    $set:{
                          "name":data.name,
                          "empId":data.empId,
                          "userName":data.userName
                          
                        }
                },{
                   upsert:true,
                   safe:false
                }